# drag file(s) from destop directly to flash webpage

Tags: flash, actionscript

Could someone please let me know if is possible to drag (multiple) files from desktop directly into a flash webpage.

If yes could you please link me to some online resources.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. Flash can load files from the user's machine only using the [FileReference](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/FileReference.html) class. The `browse()` method of that class displays a "Select file" dialog box to the user. Flash can load only those files that are selected by the user using the dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not access local files from flash in the browser, except if you use the FileReference class.

A possible way around this would be to use JavaScript. JavaScript has a new File API that will be availiable in Firefox 3.6. Read more [here](http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/drag-and-drop-upload).